# IntelliJ/structural search: Remove useless methods that only call super method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, structural-search

In one of my Android projects (but not necessarily tied to Android) I have quite a few method calls that really do nothing but blow up the code and could be automatically removed. Examples:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I couldn't find any inspections that help me in automatically removing these expressions, so I tried structural search. My attempt so far: I copied the template of 'annotated methods' and made 2 small changes.

1. $Annotation$ changed to occurs=1, text=Override
2. Added a $Statement$ variable with occurs=1

The template code:

```
class $Class$ {
    @$Annotation$( )
    $MethodType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $ParameterName$) {
        $Statement$;
    }
}
```

So far, so good - it's only finding methods with a single line in the body. But now I want to explicitely search for exact statements calling the super method (kind of like a back reference to $MethodName$), but which also return the super value (when not void). Any ideas?

I believe this would be a really useful inspection that could be integrated into the main IntelliJ codebase as well. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I recently found out that IntelliJ's 'Empty method' inspection actually looks for this. Simply:

Double Shift -> Run Inspection By Name -> Empty method

[image: method only calls its super]

The synopsis is 'Method only calls its super', but the inspection actually looks for more than just this, for example:

- The method and all its derivables are empty
- All implementations of this method are empty
- The method is empty
- Empty method overrides empty method

Depending on your situation it might find more than you want - and the refactoring tried to remove more than I actually wanted. But with a quick manual review you should be good to go. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using Structural Search you will have to use two separate searches. One for finding methods with void return type:

```
class $Class$ {
    $MethodType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $ParameterName$) {
        super.$MethodName$($ParameterName$);
    }
}
```

and a second for methods which return a value:

```
class $Class$ {
    $MethodType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $ParameterName$) {
        return super.$MethodName$($ParameterName$);
    }
}
```

Specifying the `@Override` annotation is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: No, this does not work. This template finds much more methods - not only those which call super. Though I don't know why... Also, it ignores the parameters which have to be passed to the super methods.

Comment: Oops, I should have tried this out first. It's probably a bug. I will try to get this fixed.

Comment: Searching for super methods in this way works correctly in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.